# Error (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    select 
      country_olympic_name, 
      SUM(part_gold) as 'Number of Gold Medals'
    From
      games.country,
      games.participation
   where
      participation.country_isocode = country.country_isocode
   group by
      country_olympic_name;
```

I have been getting the error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected and do not know why, please help

Comment: Do check for missing spaces in the sql query.

Comment: I ran into another instance of this error. In my case, the name I assigned to the variable was the same as a predefined function. If I changed the name or put quotation marks (not single quotes) around it, then it worked.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Identifiers need to be quoted with double quotes (`"`). Single quotes (`'`) denote a character *value* (not a "name").

Therefor you need to use:

```
SUM(part_gold) as "Number of Gold Medals"
```

More details in the manual:

- [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223)
- [Text literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)

Answer (score 5):

### Add comma after SELECT QUERY

---

In my case, I had this query

```
SELECT BANK_NAME
DECODE (SWIFT_CODE, 'BRDEROBU', 'BRD',
                   'NO RESULT') RESULT
FROM BANK_GAR;
```

As you may see, **I didn't had the comma** after the `SELECT BANK_NAME` line.

The correct query is:

```
SELECT BANK_NAME,
DECODE (SWIFT_CODE, 'BRDEROBU', 'BRD',
                   'NO RESULT') RESULT
FROM BANK_GAR;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check reserved words. This was my issue. For whatever reason using "size" as a column alias caused oracle to spit that exact error out and it had me scratching my head for a while.

```
select 1 size, 1 id from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing this:-

```
select 
  country_olympic_name, 
  SUM(part_gold) as "Number of Gold Medals"
From
  games.country,
  games.participation
where
  participation.country_isocode = country.country_isocode
group by
  country_olympic_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT
      COUNTRY_OLYMPIC_NAME,
      SUM ( PART_GOLD ) AS NUMBER_OF_GOLD_MEDALS
FROM
      GAMES.COUNTRY,
      GAMES.PARTICIPATION
WHERE
      PARTICIPATION.COUNTRY_ISOCODE = COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ISOCODE
GROUP BY
      COUNTRY_OLYMPIC_NAME;
```

Comment: that is wrong, the space is not the problem, The problem is, that it is a string, not an identifier.