# Count registrations of different user types per day

Tags: sql, oracle, count

My table looks similar to this:

```
|  date_of_register | account_type1  |  account_type2  |
| 18/11/02 23:56:59 |    type_a      |      type_b     |
```

I want to count registrations of different types of users per day. account_type1 can be type_a or null, account_type2 can be type_b or null.

the result should look for one example day like this:

```
DATE      |  registers type_a  | registers type_b|
18/11/02  |           32       |          21     |
```

But I want to make this for two months.

I'm not sure how to count records from different columns and get result like this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
SELECT 
TRUNC(date_of_register), 
COUNT(CASE WHEN account_type1 = 'type_a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "registers type_a",
COUNT(CASE WHEN account_type2 = 'type_b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "registers type_b"
FROM registrations_table 
GROUP BY TRUNC(date_of_register)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it dosent work.
ORA-00923: "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18830649/5220160 in Oracle you should use double quotes instead of single quotes for "registers type_a" and "registers type_b" - it's now changed accordingly above.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, and also i had to put type_a, type b in single quotes.
But the result is not what i expected. 
This query does not sum up all registrations for a given day, but displays each separately. so i have something like
18/09/26 12:38:55  |   1  |   0 |
for whole day every registration in other row

Comment: so your date is actually a DateTime! So then @Thorsten Kettner 's suggestion to use TRUNC is what you want. The CASE WHEN statement is useful, if for some reason you might have also other non-NULL values in your account_type columns

Answer (score 0):

You want to count occurrences per day. The day is the truncated date. So aggregate by `TRUNC(<datecolumn>)`. Counting is easy, as you merely want to count non-null occurrences, which `COUNT(<column>)` is made for.

```
select
  trunc(date_of_register),
  count(account_type1) as registers_type_a,
  count(account_type2) as registers_type_b
from mytable
group by trunc(date_of_register)
order by trunc(date_of_register);
```

Comment: It works but not completely. Now I have the result for each day separately, but the quantities are bad. For example, for 18/10/02 i have
|  18/10/02 00:00:00  |  2772 | 43
but it should be 
|  18/10/02   |  2774 | 288

In each case the difference for type a is small but for type b very large

Comment: @mistertumek - If you have edge cases you should **edit your question** to include them in your sample data.

Comment: @mistertumek: You said "account_type1 can be type_a or null, account_type2 can be type_b or null". The query counts all non-null occurrences, so it should get the results you are looking for. If this is not the case, then your data is diffferent from what you describe.